# A Discworld Riley

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, literature

> My prefix is the heir to the apprentice of the final reality,
>   Without the Ephebean "not"
>
> My suffix is both a noun and a verb
>   Dwarf Bread is *not* an example of the noun,
>   Though it may help with the verb
>
> My infix can only be found on Roundworld,
>   Though its analogue is the creators of Golden Golems
>
> I am soft and gentle, felt only quiet and stillness
>   Despite this, I contain a death within me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are a

> SUSURRATION

```
My prefix is the heir to the apprentice of the final reality,
Without the Ephebean "not"
```

> SUSAN (from, e.g., *Hogfather*) without AN -> SUS. [EDITED to add:] Why AN? Because Ephebe ~ Greece, and AN- is a Greek prefix denoting privation, which can be seen in English words like "anomie", "anhydrous" and "anarchy".

```
My suffix is both a noun and a verb
Dwarf Bread is not an example of the noun,
Though it may help with the verb
```

> RATION. Dwarf bread makes poor rations since you can't actually eat it, but as stated in *Witches Abroad* it is a good idea to take some with you on a trip because "A traveller can go for miles, just knowing there's dwarf bread in their pack. A traveller can think of just about anything to eat rather than dwarf bread including their own foot and even pumpkins".

```
My infix can only be found on Roundworld,
Though it's analogue is the creators of Golden Golems
```

> Perhaps UR, rough analogue of UM from *Making Money*. [EDITED to add:] Xenocacia points out in comments that there is actually an Ur in the Discworld books, which I'd forgotten just as much as the OP had.

```
I am soft and gentle, felt only quiet and stillness
Despite this, I contain a death within me
```

> A susurration is a murmuring, rustling or whispering. I'm not sure about the "death within me" -- perhaps this is another Pratchett reference, with the RAT indicating the *Death of Rats*, but that seems a bit far-fetched. [EDITED to add:] Turns out that that was indeed the idea.

Comment: Got it on all accounts, including the last line you weren't sure about

Comment: Great question and answer, but as a Discworld fan I just had to point out that Ur does exist in the Discworld too - its inhabitants are a byword for stupidity in the Klatchian region, and Sgt Colon skillfully (?) passed off as one in Jingo.